# Laravel: Font awesome icons not showing in production mode

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

I have installed font-awesome with Laravel using this guide: https://dev.to/dendihandian/adding-font-awesome-to-laravel-the-laravel-mix-way-4ndj. Icons are showing perfectly fine on my local machine but not in production mode. I have tried to run "npm run prod" but still not working.

Webpack.mix.js file:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .copy(
        'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts',
        'public/webfonts'
    )
    .sourceMaps()
    .version(['public/js/app.js']);
```

Icons loaded:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('dashboard')}}"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('vendors.index') }}"><i class="fa fa-building"></i><span>Vendors</span></a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('estimates.index') }}"><i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i><span>Estimates</span></a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('customers.index') }}"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span>Customers</span></a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('projects.index') }}"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i><span>Projects</span></a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('services.index') }}"><i class="fa fa-cube"></i><span>Services</span></a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('users.index') }}"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><span>Users</span></a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span>Settings</span></a>
</li>
```

[image: network status]

Comment: Did you do the `@import` step in the guide you linked?

Comment: yes, I did in app.scss.

Comment: i figured out this has something to do with .htaccess on my production environment